# Trying to create a Javascript function that sums up numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm super new to Javascript and I'm trying to write a function that sums up numbers. 
The function below returns "0" instead of the sum (and I have no idea why).

```
function sumTo(N) {
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
  total = total + N[i];
 }
 return total;
 };
 console.log(sumTo(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: shouldn't you send values in an array?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to get `length` from a number (the first number you pass to your function; `1` in your example). Numbers don't have a length, so you get `undefined`, and `0 < undefined` is false, so your loop never runs.

Either:

1. Pass an *array* into `sumTo`

   ```
   console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
   // Note ----------^-------------^
   ```

   or
2. Use the `arguments` automatic local variable

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length ++i) {
       total += arguments[i];
   }
   ```

   or
3. Use ES2015's "rest" arguments:

   ```
   // ES2015+ only!
   function sumTo(...values) {
      let total = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          total += values[i];
      }
      return total;
   }
   ```

   Since you're in ES2015 at that point, you could use `reduce` with an arrow function (sums are a perfect use case for `reduce`):

   ```
   // ES2015+ only!
   function sumTo(...values) {
      let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      return total;
   }
   ```

   Or `for-of`, another ES2015 thing:

   ```
   // ES2015+ only!
   function sumTo(...values) {
      let total = 0;
      for (let value of total) {
          total += value;
      }
      return total;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `N` is just the first argument, which in this case is `1`. `1` has no index, thus `N[1]` does not work.

What you need is to pass in an array, since you're expecting `N` to have `length`.

```
console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need either an array for the numbers, or use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
function sumTo(N) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
        total = total + N[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

With arguments

```js
function sumTo(N) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        total = total + arguments[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(sumTo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

With ES6, you could use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `...`.

```js
function sumTo(...N) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
        total = total + N[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(sumTo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Comment: In the second function - there's no need for `N` since you just use `arguments` right?

Comment: Nit: Rest syntax isn't an operator.

Comment: right, the `N` is actually superfluous, but there a some occasions where it might be necessary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, [Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#spreadrest) speaks from *"`...` operator"*. when has it changed to rest parameter?

Comment: @NinaScholz: If Kyle says that, he's mistaken (or more likely just speaking loosely). An operator has a *result*. Rest (in either of its incarnations) doesn't have a result, and couldn't have results that would do what they do. Rest (and spread) are just syntax, like the `()` on `for` constructs aren't the grouping operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use reduce method :

```
var sumTo = ar => ar.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you should send your values in an array:

```js
function sumTo(N) {
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
    total = total + N[i];
  }
  return total;
};
console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

As an alternate, you can use `Array.reduce`

```js
function sumTo(N) {
  return N.reduce(function(p,c){
    return p+c
  })
};
console.log(sumTo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```